# webpage returns 405 status code error when accessed with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, http-status-code-405

I am trying to scrap below URL with scrapy -

https://www.realtor.ca/Residential/Single-Family/18279532/78-80-BURNDEAN-Court-Richmond-Hill-Ontario-L4C0K1-Westbrook#v=n

but, It always ends up giving status 405 error. I have searched about this topic but they always say that it occurs when the request method is incorrect, like POST in place of GET. But this is surely not the case here.

here is my code for spider -

```
import scrapy

class sampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.realtor.ca/Residential/Single-Family/18279532/78-80-BURNDEAN-Court-Richmond-Hill-Ontario-L4C0K1-Westbrook#v=n']

    def parse(self, response):


        yield {
            'response' : response.body_as_unicode(),
        }
```

and here is the log I get when I run the scraper -

```
PS D:\> scrapy runspider tst.py -o tst.csv
2017-06-26 19:20:49 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-06-26 19:20:49 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': 'tst.csv'}
2017-06-26 19:20:49 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-06-26 19:20:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-06-26 19:20:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-06-26 19:20:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-06-26 19:20:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-06-26 19:20:50 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min
)
2017-06-26 19:20:50 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-06-26 19:20:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (405) <GET https://www.realtor.ca/Residential/Single-Family/1827
9532/78-80-BURNDEAN-Court-Richmond-Hill-Ontario-L4C0K1-Westbrook#v=n> (referer: None)
2017-06-26 19:20:51 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <405 https://www.realtor.ca/Residential
/Single-Family/18279532/78-80-BURNDEAN-Court-Richmond-Hill-Ontario-L4C0K1-Westbrook>: HTTP status code is not handled or
 not allowed
2017-06-26 19:20:51 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-06-26 19:20:51 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 306,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 9360,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/405': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 26, 13, 50, 51, 432000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 26, 13, 50, 50, 104000)}
2017-06-26 19:20:51 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's because you are including `#v=n` in the request. Everything after the # in a URL should not be sent to the server. The hash anchor is local to the browser. Try removing that and it should fix the 405.

Comment: @drew010  still the same problem...
Actually when i opened this url in scrapy shell.
And rendered the response in browser.
It had captha in it. So, they somehow knew that the request was not coming from a browser but a bot or a script.

Comment: Make sure it sends a user agent string that matches a common browser and that the IP isn't restricted. I'll see what else it may be

Comment: @drew010 It opens good in browser, so ip is good. Also I have set the user agent in setting.py, still no success.

Comment: The user agent prevented me from getting a 405, but a normal response first serves a page with only JavaScript content.  The JS serves as a browser test.  When you load the page in the browser it's evaluating the JS and letting you pass.  If you use the network console in your browser you'll see that after you load the initial page it issues a GET and POST request to a JS file with a long name. This does some browser fingerprinting and sends the results back. If they like them you can view the site.  You'll likely need a browser emulator like Selenium for this.

Comment: Is it possible to use splash here..

Comment: It looks like that might work.  I have no experience with Splash so I couldn't give any guidance off hand.  It might be fairly simple to reverse engineer the JS at https://www.realtor.ca/cndnrlsttdstlxqbqduyvbcretuqryc.js which is the JS browser test but if they make a tiny change your code will break.  Much safer to emulate it.

Comment: Thank you for your help buddy. Really appreciate it..

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!  Roadblocks like this are no fun but are getting pretty common.  Amazon performs a similar check just to log in.  Once you get a JS engine integrated it should be really simple to pass.  The hardest part is learning how to use it and get it working with your code.

Comment: I will figure it out. Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar problem trying to scrape [www.funda.nl](http://www.funda.nl) and solved it by

1. changing the user agent (using https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-random-useragent/),
2. using [Scrapy Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash).

This may work for the website you're trying to scrape as well (although I haven't tested this).

Comment: This still does not work. Funda uses Distil networks. They can still tell that you are using a scraper. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any update whether there is working solution now? I am also into funda.nl :)