# Scrapy Web Scraping return 405

Tags: web-scraping

I made a simple spider in Scrapy with python to get the title from some websites.I get this 405 error which can be seen in the photo from one website and the other one is good it returns me 200. Do you know what the problem may be?

https://postimg.cc/gallery/2pbx9j7wy/

I searched a lot for this question but i couldnt find it. If you can give me a full answer or just some links i would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

It is different of what is linked here because i encounter a captcha...

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.5 i found this, but i don't know how i can write that

Comment: I also tried changing USER_AGENT still not solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webpage returns 405 status code error when accessed with scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761497/webpage-returns-405-status-code-error-when-accessed-with-scrapy)

Comment: It is different because i encounter a captcha...

Answer (score 0):

So Http 405 is method not allowed. What does this mean?
There is the simple GET request, that happens when you type an URL in the browser. There is also POST which is usually used when submitting a form. What this error means in your case most probably is that the URL expects something different than GET, and given that this is some kind of captcha most probably it expects POST. Check the FormRequest class in scrapy documentation on how to make a post request.

Comment: I don't know how to get it working.Can you show me an example based on my code? By the way, I'm here: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

Comment: I just want to print the title like i did with the quotestoscrape

Comment: I might be able to do it, but you have to give me somehow access to the code. Just the spider will be enough.

Comment: I checked this repo. First why do you need the selenium? Also in the repo I couldn't see any configuration regarding selenium.
I don't know what you are trying to do there, but this is a captcha you are trying to pass by, and I opened the site and it showed me the google recaptcha. This is not trivial to solve. you might want to use some ready service for this like http://antigate.com/.
Scrapy is simply a framework for fetching HTML and extracting data from it, passing captchas is well beyond its scope.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your time! Now I understand this not trivial because i searched like 20 hours on google for an answer and found nothing.